# Image Upload with Ajax and jquery in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**[Previous Problem Solved]**
I downloaded an image upload script which works with Ajax and jQuery. I want to limit the max upload to 8 images only. Please help.

Downloaded From: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-upload-multiple-images-jquery-ajax-using-php_453.html

Comment: did you get any error on console.. and also did you change your folder location there?

Comment: no... console is blank.. no errors..

Comment: no.. no location changed.. all are in place..

Comment: where is your files are being uploaded .. please add some more details there

Comment: that problem solved... help me with limiting the max image upload to 8 only

Answer (score 0):

Count all files and check there if files are more than 8 or not if there are more than 8 send a message    and exit ;

**something like this**

```
  $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);

if($fileCount>8){
$data['code'] = "failed";
print_r(json_encode($data));exit;
}
```

and in your ajax do whatever you want to do ..

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this.

```
$allfiles = count($_FILES);
if($allfiles > 8)
{
  echo "Sorry You can Upload Only 8 images";
}
else{
    //your code here
 }
```